# Spring Localization without passing language in query string

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization

I am working on one web app project which supports multiple languages.

I am using Spring framework. Spring has option to support multiple language by adding the following beans in dispatcher servlet.

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="language" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Register the messages.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

The localization works only if I pass language parameter in every URL.

Is there any option to set locale based on the client's browser language?

Comment: Replace `SessionLocaleResolver` with `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` and remove the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` (as you won't be able to change it then). It would also work if you remove the `defaultLocale` property from the `SessionLocaleResolver` because when not set it will use the one received from the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websites implement localization in one of two ways. The first approach involves automatically detecting the user locale by examining HTTP request headers (`Accept-Language` header in particular) and localizing site content for the user locale (if supported).

Spring MVC uses this approach by default. It uses the `HttpServletRequest.getLocale` method to determine the client locale and then loads localized messages from message sources. Note that the `getLocale` method returns a single `Locale` object whereas the `Accept-Language` header passed by the client could contain multiple languages (for example, `Accept-Language: en-US, en-GB, en`). In such cases, the `getLocale` method returns the `Locale` for the first matching language (`en-US` in the example above).

Therefore, if you wish your Spring MVC application to automatically detect the client locale and serve localized content, simply declare a `ResourceBundleMessageSource` bean in the application context. No other configuration is required.

See [my sample application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41032674) that demonstrates this approach. Use a browser extension such as Postman for Chrome to manipulate the value of the `Accept-Language` header. The sample supports English, French, German and Spanish so passing `en-US`, `fr-FR`, `de-DE` and `es-ES` will show localized messages in each of these languages respectively.

---

The second approach used by websites is to always display content in a default language first and then allowing the user to change the locale (using a dropdown or links in the site header or footer). In such cases, the users may choose locales that are not consistent with the `Accept-Language` header sent by their browser. For example, the `Accept-Language` header may contain `fr-CH` while the user may select `de-DE` as the locale.

It is in such scenarios that `LocaleChangeInterceptor` and `SessionLocaleResolver` are required to use the user selection instead of the request headers. These components can intercept the user choice and save it temporarily for the duration of the session to localize the site content correctly.